# Create program to find length of a String

Tags: java, swing

I created a program for finding string length.

This my code:

```
    JTInputString = JTextfild ( For input )
    JLResult = Jlabel ( For Show Lenght )



    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package UIs;

/**
 *
 * @author Mr-Enginner
 */
public class String extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form String
     */
    public String() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(java.lang.String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new String().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        JTInputString = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        JBCalculate = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        JLResult = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JBCalculate.setText("محاسبه طول رشته");
        JBCalculate.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                JBCalculateActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setText("طول رشته :");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(JTInputString)
                .addContainerGap())
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(134, 134, 134)
                .addComponent(JBCalculate)
                .addContainerGap(147, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(JLResult)
                .addGap(104, 104, 104)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(43, 43, 43))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(45, 45, 45)
                .addComponent(JTInputString, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 46, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(JBCalculate)
                .addGap(39, 39, 39)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(JLResult))
                .addContainerGap(115, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void JBCalculateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        Lenght();
        Clearform();
    }                                           

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(String.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(String.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(String.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(String.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new String().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton JBCalculate;
    private javax.swing.JLabel JLResult;
    private javax.swing.JTextField JTInputString;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   

public void Lenght(){
        String Str=JTInputString.getText();
        int str=Str.length();
       JLResult.setText(""+str);
}
public void Clearform(){
    JTInputString.setText("");
    JLResult.setText("");
}



}
```

and i using this code . but not show any thing :

```
java.lang.String Str = JTInputString.getText();
int str = Str.length();
JLResult.setText("" + str);
```

But it does not show me count in `JLResult`.

What's the problem?

Error

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to UIs.String
>       at UIs.String.Lenght(String.java:137)
>       at UIs.String.JBCalculateActionPerformed(String.java:90)
>       at UIs.String.access$000(String.java:12)
>       at UIs.String$2.actionPerformed(String.java:47)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Comment: I recommend posting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to clarify the exact context of the problem.

Comment: You're kidding, right? You've already got it in `Str.length()`. No need for the for loop. Your method should be called length, don't need java.lang prior to String and your variables should start with lower case letters. Hope that helps :)

Comment: When i using `String str=JTInputString` show me error

Comment: If you are getting an error, you should post what the specific error you are getting is.

Comment: Is JTInputString a variable, or a subclass of JTextField?

Comment: @ManoDestra `JTextField`

Comment: Can you post the whole code or the error you're getting?

Comment: No, I mean is it a variable or a subclass? Need to see your entire code and your error here.

Comment: @ManoDestra it's a variable that starts with a capital

Comment: Ok. If you use correct naming conventions, then it makes spotting errors so much easier. Post the full code and the error you're getting as part of the body of your question.

Comment: You're using a different String class, that's why: `UIs.String`. Do NOT call your main class String. Your code is getting extremely confused because of the naming clash. Ensure that you name your variables and classes appropriately.

Comment: Hint: really, your code is one huge **mess**. Seriously: while you are on such a beginner level, don't go for UI applications. Better learn how to crawl, before trying to do high-speed hurdle racing.

Comment: Also, the description of your problem in your question did not actually match your real problem. The posting of the error stack trace was entirely irrelevant to your issue. Just a thing to consider for future questions. Ensure that you post your code and describe the actual problem (giving relevant stack trace, if required).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the text of the label, and then immediately clearing it.

```
private void JBCalculateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    Lenght();
    Clearform(); // <-- Remove this line
}
```

Alternately:

```
public void Clearform() {
    JTInputString.setText("");
    JLResult.setText("");    // <-- Remove this line
}
```

Comment: What was the point of the stack trace that you posted if that was not actually your problem?

Answer (score 1):

The answer here is to name your class more appropriately. You have a naming clash between `java.lang.String` and your JFrame `UIs.String`.

Call your main frame TestFrame or something more meaningful to your application to avoid the naming clash.

Also, ensure that your variable names all start with lower case letters. You're making variables look like classes at the moment. You will end up in a lot of problems later, if you don't follow the standard Java coding standards and conventions.

The Google Java standards are as good as any. I recommend you [check them out](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html).

**EDIT:**

This answer was given to your posted question including the stack trace regarding inability to compile.

There was a subsequent issue regarding your Clearform() method as that was clearing the values of your controls. The issue regarding Clearform() should have been a separate question to this current question.

Comment: no . i guess for lang.string . When i used this String Show Error

Comment: See your stack trace: `Uncompilable source code - incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to UIs.String at `

Comment: Re: "EDIT".  Actually, the original question was about the `Clearform()` issue.  The stack trace is the red herring that was added afterwards when someone asked what error the OP got when they used `String` instead of `java.lang.String`.